# Replace all columns in pandas dataframe with one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
    0    1    2    3    4
0   a    b    c    d    e
1   f    g    h    i    j
2   k    l    m    n    o
3   p    q    r    s    t
```

I want to replace all the columns in the dataframe with the values in `column 1`, so the result would be

```
    0    1    2    3    4
0   b    b    b    b    b
1   g    g    g    g    g
2   l    l    l    l    l
3   q    q    q    q    q
```

How would you do it pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrst')).reshape(-1, 5))
print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  f  g  h  i  j
2  k  l  m  n  o
3  p  q  r  s  t
```

Reconstruct

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df[1].values] * len(df.columns)),
    df.index, df.columns
)

   0  1  2  3  4
0  b  b  b  b  b
1  g  g  g  g  g
2  l  l  l  l  l
3  q  q  q  q  q
```

Comment: i tried doing this with my dataframe and it says "assign() keywords must be strings.

My dataframe actually has numerical values in its entries, not strings; probably should have clarified that in the post but i thought it wouldnt matter

Comment: @Ted that makes sense.  It's passing the existing column values as keyword arguments.  It can't use integers as keyword arguments.  You can get around this with some shenanigans... but why bother, my other solution or Divakar's will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: the reconstruction method you posted works so I'm going to go with that

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be using `[:]` to do assignment across all columns and using `iloc[:,[1]]` to select `col-1` keeping the column format -

```
df[:] = df.iloc[:,[1]] # Or df[['1']] if column names are in
               # string sequence from 0 as suggested by @piRSquared
```

Sample run -

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  f  g  h  i  j
2  k  l  m  n  o
3  p  q  r  s  t

In [16]: df[:] = df.iloc[:,[1]]

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  b  b  b  b  b
1  g  g  g  g  g
2  l  l  l  l  l
3  q  q  q  q  q
```

---

**Handling mixed dtype dataframes**

If you are dealing with mixed datatype columns, i.e. not all columns being of the same datatype as the column-1, we need to make it same dtype and one method to do so would be converting all columns to `'object'` dtype. Then, we can use the earlier suggested method. Thus, the conversion and assignment steps would be -

```
df = df.astype('object')
df[:] = df.iloc[:,[1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [267]: df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(10))
     ...: S = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,9,(18)))
     ...: df[1] = S
     ...: 

In [268]: df
Out[268]: 
     0  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  NaN  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [269]: df = df.astype('object')
     ...: df[:] = df.iloc[:,[1]]
     ...: 

In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
1  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
```

Comment: You can shorten it up further `df[:] = df[['1']]`  assuming the column names are strings.

Comment: sorry, i think i should have clarified my question more. The column names are numerical and the indexes are numerical.

When i try your method the other columns i want to replace end up with NaNs

Comment: not sure what to say, but its not working. here's literally what I do step by step.

I have a variable S of type pandas.core.series.Series whose output is:
`S

0      99999
1          298
2      99999
3          298
4          298
`
I create a new dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(18), columns=range(10))`

set one column of the dataframe to that series

`df[1] = S`

and try to extend that column to the rest of the columns

`df[:] = df.iloc[:,[1]]` 

I feel as your answer should be the most commonly used one, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @Ted The issue was that col-1 was int dtype, whereas others were float or object. So, we needed dtype conversion there. Added section at the end on it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.tile` to repeat

```
In [1207]: pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df[1].values[:, np.newaxis], len(df.columns)))
Out[1207]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  b  b  b  b  b
1  g  g  g  g  g
2  l  l  l  l  l
3  q  q  q  q  q
```

---

Details

```
In [1208]: df
Out[1208]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  e
1  f  g  h  i  j
2  k  l  m  n  o
3  p  q  r  s  t
```